# How to get time intervals on STM32?

Tags: time, stm32, microprocessors

I want to measure how long does a single function take on STM32. The only thing I could find is `SysTick_Handler`. However, that is an periodic interrupt, but what I need is get time interval like:

```
long t1 = mcu_clock();
sleep(20);
long t2 = mcu_clock();
long diff = (t2 - t1);
```

I've tried C `clock()`, but it didn't work and always return `-1`. How can I make it?

Comment: Increment a variable in the `SysTick_Handler` and query that variable.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Is that the only solution? It seems like a workaround.

Comment: You have to set up a timer in either way and keep track of it. The easiest to use the sys tick and a simple variable. The official HAL library from ST does it the same way, example: [stm32F0xx_hal.c](https://github.com/wemos/Motor_Shield_Firmware/blob/master/Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal.c)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, enable the cycle counter once at startup:

```
CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk;
DWT->CYCCNT = 0;
DWT->CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk;
```

then, you can access its value:

```
unsigned long t1 = DWT->CYCCNT;
/* do something */
unsigned long t2 = DWT->CYCCNT;
unsigned long diff = t2 - t1;
```

It counts the elapsed cpu cycles, you have to divide it with the cpu clock frequency to get a value in seconds.

As it's a 32 bit value, it can overflow quite fast at higher clock frequencies, e.g in 19.88 seconds at 216 MHz.

Comment: Very useful answer. ;-)

Comment: what is DWT? I could not find a reference to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you've got HAL available try;

```
int millis = HAL_GetTick();
```