# How to write and read an I2C eeprom using stm32f100 board

Tags: c, stm32, eeprom

I' m working in team on a project using stm32 f100 series board. I should use an external I2C eeprom to storage some data, the eeprom is the following: CAT24C512WI-GT3 and I also have the init code for this I2C eeprom:

```
void io_ee_scl(char s)
{
    if(s)
        GPIOB->BSRR=GPIO_PIN_6;
    else
        GPIOB->BRR=GPIO_PIN_6;
}

void io_ee_sda(char s)
{
    if(s)
        GPIOB->BSRR=GPIO_PIN_7;
    else
        GPIOB->BRR=GPIO_PIN_7;

}

void io_ee_wp(char s)
{
    if(s)
        GPIOB->BSRR=GPIO_PIN_5;
    else
        GPIOB->BRR=GPIO_PIN_5;
}
char read_eeprom()  //read eeprom function
{
    return ( (GPIOB->IDR&GPIO_PIN_7) ? 1 : 0 );
}
```

On internet the most guide talk about HAL library but as you can see my colleague doesn't use the HAL library and considering I am new in stm32 I don't know how to read and write data on the eeprom.
Some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is no init code, but a part of the system-specific code for a software-only (a.k.a. bit-banging) I<sup>2</sup>C driver.

in addition to this, you have to

- enable the GPIOB peripheral clock in `RCC->APB2ENR`
- put both pins in *open-drain, general purpose output* mode in `GPIOB->CRL`
- have a [delay function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246125/how-to-get-time-intervals-on-stm32/42246704#42246704) for 1/2 of the I<sup>2</sup>C clock cycle time, i.e. if it should be running at 100 kHz, a single cycle takes 10 μs, you'd need a delay of 5 μs.

Then it's possible to use [general I<sup>2</sup>C code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Example_of_bit-banging_the_I%C2%B2C_master_protocol) to communicate with the EEPROM. The communication protocol is described in detail in the [EEPROM datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT24C512-D.PDF).

It is also possible to use the built in I<sup>2</sup>C peripheral of the STM32F1, but it'd be quite challenging as the first task on this platform for a beginner. Nevertheless, if you'd like to do it, you can *study* the relevant HAL source code to see how it is done there.